# for loops regarding unknown errors

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax-error

I have an assignment for school that I need to complete, these are the criteria, Count every number 0 - 35
Count every number 0 - 50,  start from 30 and stop at 50
Count by 5's 0 - 50
Count down from 10 to 0
Count down from 100 - 0 by 10's
Count every odd number from 1-30
all doing that with for loops
so here is what i have so far, and for some reason it is not working

```
 <html>
<body>
<script>
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++){ 
document.write(i);

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my question is what am I doing wrong? it comes up with an unexpected identifier but thats all it says.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare a data type (int) in JavaScript. JavaScript is a loosely-typed language. There are only strings, numbers, booleans as primitive data types and the type you get is dependent on how you implicitly (or explicitly) use them.

Here, the variable `i` is initialized to `0`, which is a valid number. When the JavaScript runtime sees you attempting to add to it, it allows that because it has implicitly known that `i` should be categorized as a number:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++){ 
  document.write(i);
}

// And, just for fun...
var a = 5;
var b = "5";
console.log("a's type is: " +  typeof a);
console.log("b's type is: " +  typeof b);

// But, you can coerce a value into a different type:
console.log("parseInt(b) results in: " + typeof parseInt(b));
console.log('a + "" results in: ' + typeof (a + ""));
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) some good reading on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

there is no type called 'int' in javascript use 'var'

```
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++){ 
 document.write(i);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` is no good in Javascript.  Everything is defined as `var`.
Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++){ 
    document.write(i);
}
```